# iOS - Memory leak AddressBook

Tags: ios, memory, memory-leaks, addressbook

I was working around AddressBook framework when I've found out some memory leak of different types in my application :

```
Leaked Object   #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
__NSCFArray 8   < multiple >    256 Bytes   AddressBook ABCMultiValueInsertAndCreateIdentifier
__NSCFString    7   < multiple >    224 Bytes   AppSupport  _sqliteStatementApplyValuesFromRecordWithNullValue
Malloc 32 Bytes 8   < multiple >    256 Bytes   AddressBook ABCMultiValueInsertAndCreateIdentifier
__NSCFArray 8   < multiple >    256 Bytes   AddressBook ABCMultiValueInsertAndCreateIdentifier
ABCMultiValue   8   < multiple >    256 Bytes   AddressBook ABCMultiValueCreate
Malloc 32 Bytes 7   < multiple >    224 Bytes   AddressBook ABCMultiValueInsertAndCreateIdentifier
__NSCFArray 7   < multiple >    224 Bytes   AddressBook ABCMultiValueInsertAndCreateIdentifier
Malloc 32 Bytes 5   < multiple >    160 Bytes   AddressBook ABCMultiValueInsertAndCreateIdentifier
```

Here's my code :

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {

    SDAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    ABMultiValueRef multiRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    NSString *number = (__bridge NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiRef, 0);
    NSString *firstname = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *lastname = (__bridge NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    number = (number ? number : @"");
    firstname = (firstname ? firstname : @"");
    lastname = (lastname ? lastname : @"");

    NSDictionary *dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:number, firstname, lastname, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:kSDPhoneNumberKey, kSDFirstnameKey, kSDLastnameKey, nil]];

    NSMutableArray *numberArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.contactArray];
    [numberArray addObject:dic];

    [appDelegate setContactArray:numberArray];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;
}
```

Do someone know which lines are responsible for these leaks ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, any Core Foundation method that has `Copy` or `Create` in the name should either transfer ownership to your ARC objects or you must call `CFRelease` yourself. Thus, you should transfer ownership for your three `NSString` objects, and manually release `multiRef`.

To transfer ownership to ARC you should use `CFBridgingRelease`, which according to [WWDC 2012 - Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405) (about 37:35 into the video), is now preferred over the previous technique, `__bridging_transfer` (even though, behind the scenes, they're the same thing).

Anyway, the declarations of your three `NSString` objects should be:

```
NSString *number = CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiRef, 0));
NSString *firstname = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
NSString *lastname = CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
```

This is equivalent to:

```
NSString *number = (__bridge_transfer NSString *) ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiRef, 0);
NSString *firstname = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
NSString *lastname = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
```

Also, don't forget to release `multiRef`, too:

```
CFRelease(multiRef);
```

By the way, if you ran the static analyzer, I believe it would have pointed these out for you. Choose "Analyze" from the "Product" menu, or press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot ! No more memory leaks and Analyze tool is amazing, i didn't know it was there !